# How should I convince my manger to give me interesting work?

Tags: software-industry, professionalism

I've been working on the same technology for the past year.

Almost 6 months back, I asked my manager to either give me some interesting work or switch me to some other technology which the company uses.

Every time I ask him to do something, he keeps on delaying.

I don't want to leave the organization but neither do I want to stay away from new technologies.

Comment: Convince him it's worthwhile to do.

Comment: The answer to this may be dependent on which culture this is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Make sure you’ve done a great job on the assignments that you’ve
  completed. Can you document that you’ve finished all your
  responsibilities ahead of time and exceeded expectations? Your
  ability to demonstrate why you should have more challenges impresses
  your boss. He/she will know you take your job seriously and want to
  add value to the company.
- Be careful not to belittle any efforts by other co-workers who may be performing the same tasks as you. Choose your language carefully when your boss asks why you want more
  responsibility. Instead of using words like “boring,” or “repetitive”
  to describe your dissatisfaction with your assignments, explain that
  you want to do more to develop your skills and to help the company
  reach its goals. You may even add that you’re willing to continue
  your original assignments but want more challenging work in the
  company, even if it means working longer hours.
- Do some research before you approach your boss. In other words, be
  careful what you ask for because you might get it. You can ensure
  that your new tasks will be ones that you’ll enjoy if you have
  participated in selecting them. Also, you’ll be much more successful
  if you pick fresh challenges that showcase your talents. If you’re
  excellent at research, ask if you can work on a research project. If
  you’re a computer whiz, suggest an assignment in that area. Prepare a
  brief report, outlining potential new challenges along with goals and
  timelines. How can your boss say no?

Comment: I have completed all my assignments on time.
Not only this, but also i have completed everything before time...

Comment: Then bring these points to him...convince him you can do it and not only that but deserve it.

Answer (score 1):

Your boss's reaction is perfectly understandable. You come to him with a problem (which is not even a real problem for the company) without providing him any solutions. You could be making your overworked boss's life easier. He will react better to you saying "Here is a problem, here are my three possible solutions. Choose one and I can work on it."

Maybe it depends in the business or company, but surely you can find interesting projects that are falling through the cracks (i.e. need to be done and no one is doing them). I've always been able to find them in my experience.

Caution: initially, you should work on these projects on your own time, or on project down time. You may not know the context, and you may discover that what you thought was important is actually irrelevant to the company. Regardless, you will likely have learned something new even doing an irrelevant project, which is one of your goals.

Answer (score 0):

**Ask for it**

Your boss is generally trying to match tasks that are appropriate to skill levels. A good boss is trying to maximize your output. In asking for a task he'll see that you have interest in the task. People tend to do better work on thing they have interest in or have a passion for. If you boss is aware that you want it and he feel you'll a great job on it, you'll get it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're unhappy to continue as it is, make a firm statement that unless the situation is addressed you consider leaving.

Obviously be prepared for "I call your bluff", as I'd estimate chances over 80%.

The alternative IME is sour, if your comments and requests are ignored for long time, all chances are that will stay that way. So your choice is limited to suck up the situation or find greener pastures elsewhere.   OTOH sometimes your input is noted just with low priority, and forcing the issue may get that up actually.